# Rest Api pagination - same path for links (self, next, last)

Tags: rest, http, pagination, get, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm building an ETL process based on REST CALL API to get transactional information from PayPayl. To do so, I use the HTTP plugin in Data Fusion on GCP.

PayPal uses pagination and set the maximum limit of 500 transactions per page. In order to get results from another one, I need to provide a path to the link that contains another set of results. Here's the screen from the documentation:

[image]

This example is pretty straight forward, but it's not so easy in my case, here's the result of PayPal query:

[image]

Basically, in my example all three links have same path - links/href

I've tried many things like `links[2]/href`, `links[] | select(.rel=="next")`, `links[?rel=='next'].href` but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to properly indicate the path for URL with NEXT page?

Answer (score 1):

In your use case "Link in Response Body" pagination type will not work because  it does not support arrays in the expression.
The solution is to use "Custom" pagination type and provide a short python snippet to extract the value you need.

Comment: Thank you. This is a viable solution, however, something esle also worked, which is:
pagination type - increment and index with &page={pagination.index}